# php json response formatting as per requirement

Tags: php, json, api

I am returning json response to api, using `json_encode()` method.
I have array which is where a key users can have multiple user or no user i.e empty array,and key course is either empty or can have single object as below

```
{
"success": true,
"code": 200,
"message": "",
"result": {
    "users": [],
    "course": []
}
```

}

if it has data the response is like this

```
{
  "success": true,
  "code": 200,
  "message": "",
  "result": {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Vishal",
            "Age": 25
        },
        {
            "name": "Akshay",
            "Age": 29
        }
    ],
    "course": {
        "name": "xyz"
    }
  }
 }
```

but what i want is users should be array in both cases and course should return as object in both cases. is it possible.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force course entry to be object before json encoding.

```
 $ret["result"]["course"] = (object)$course;
```